# Transit visa Australia

Tags: australia, transit-visas, brazilian-citizens

I'm Brazilian and I was living in Australia until July using a student visa. I then left the country because I had no further period of stay in my visa. I went to New Zealand to apply for a new student visa and it was denied.

Now I want to go to Indonesia for tourism before returning to Brazil, but most of the flights pass by Australia. I want to go as soon as possible; do you think they could deny my transit visa? I'm scared to buy the ticket and have the visa denied! How long would they take to answer the application? I am hoping to buy a flight for the end of the week or early next week.

Answer (score 4):

As a citizen of Brazil, you are not eligible for [transit without visa](https://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/transit/no-visa.htm), so you will have to apply for a [transit visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/771.aspx) (771).

If you have an onward flight ticket to your home country, I think the odds you being granted the visa are quite high, but of course this is fully up to Australian immigration.  You will also have to purchase your ticket before you can apply.

That said, you don't need to go via Australia, since there are [plenty of alternative routes](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bali/Sao-Paulo-Brazil) that should not require a visa for an airside transit, in particular if you go via the Middle East: Dubai/Abu Dhabi (UAE), Qatar, etc.